# How can I delete an event using the Eventbrite API?

Tags: eventbrite

The `event.status` field doesn't appear to be modifiable directly, and I can't find anything in the docs about deleting events. How can I go about deleting an event via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no endpoint for deleting an event, though this is something we will be adding later. For now, you can unpublish events via this endpoint http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-post-events-id-unpublish.